# Convergence of $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{0}^{\infty} ne^{-nx} \frac{x^2+1}{x^2+x+1}dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I want to show that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{0}^{\infty} ne^{-nx} \frac{x^2+1}{x^2+x+1} dx$ exists and compute its value.

First I need to show that $ne^{-nx} \frac{x^2+1}{x^2+x+1}$ is integrable.

I think that the problem comes from when $x$ is large. Thus I wanted to say something like, if $x \rightarrow \infty$, then $\frac{x^2+1}{x^2+x+1} \sim 1$ and we have that $ne^{-nx} \frac{x^2+1}{x^2+x+1} \sim ne^{-nx}$ which is integrable for all $n$.

Does that make sense?

If I then apply the dominated convergence theorem to $f_n = ne^{-nx} \frac{x^2+1}{x^2+x+1}$ I'd get $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{0}^{\infty} ne^{-nx} \frac{x^2+1}{x^2+x+1}dx = 0$ right?

I'm really confused and would be thankful if someone could comment on this.

Comment: First, your justification for integrability is right, but it's pretty superficial. Do you know how to fill in the details? So what if $ne^{-nx} \frac{x^2+1}{x^2+x+1} \sim ne^{-nx}$? If $f(x) \sim g(x)$ and $g$ is integrable, what lets you conclude that $f$ is integrable? Second, just saying "apply the dominated convergence theorem" isn't enough. You actually have to apply it. If you did, you would find that the limit you guessed is incorrect.

Comment: A hint: Substitute $y = nx$.

Comment: Thank you for your help Antonio. 
$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} ne^{-nx} \rightarrow 0$ right? So $f_n \rightarrow 0$ no?

Comment: Pointwise, sure. But what's the key part of the dominated convergence theorem? **What's your domination function?** The dominated convergence theorem is not just "$f_n \to 0$ pointwise implies $\int f_n \to 0$". There's a reason it has "dominated" in the name.

Comment: I have the following theorem:
Suppose that $f_n$ are measurable and $f_n(x) \rightarrow f(x)$, for all $x$.
If there exists $g$ integrable such that $|f_n| \leq g$, then $\lim \int f_n = \int f$.

Comment: Indeed, you have not said what your $g$ would be! That's the dominating function.

Comment: I wanted to do something like:
$|ne^{-nx} \frac{x^2+1}{x^2+x+1}| \leq |\frac{(x^2+1)n}{e^x}|$ but then I'm stuck...
I want to get rid of the $n$ but don't know how

Comment: First, $g$ must not have an $n$ in it. Second, the point I'm trying to make is that **there is no such $g$**. It seems like it would be a good exercise for you to convince yourself of this. You can't prove that $\int f_n \to 0$ in this case because it's not true!

Comment: I see, so I can't just apply DCT directly (see comment below)
Thank you Antonio, you were really helpful. I figured that DCT didn't work here but wanted it absolutely to work directly !

Comment: Correct. But you have been given two different approaches where you can eventually use the DCT. The first was in [my second comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2965355/convergence-of-lim-n-rightarrow-infty-int-0-infty-ne-nx-fracx2?noredirect=1#comment6121739_2965355), and the second was in Umberto's answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help ! It is clearer now !

Comment: Glad to help.${}$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84761/discussion-between-riri92-and-antonio-vargas).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the dominated convergence theorem, if $f(x)$ is a bounded function on $\mathbb{R}^+$ we have (provided that the RHS makes sense)
$$ \lim_{n\to +\infty}\int_{0}^{+\infty} n e^{-nx} f(x)\,dx = \lim_{x\to 0^+} f(x) $$
since $\int_{0}^{+\infty} n e^{-nx}\,dx = 1$ but $n e^{-nx}$ gets more and more concentrated around the origin as $n$ increases. 
*Approximate identities* are pretty useful for showing
$$ \lim_{x\to 0^+}\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\sin(nx)}{n} = \frac{\pi}{2}$$
and similar identities, for instance.

Answer (score 2):

It is evident that $\int_0^\infty ne^{-nx} \, dx = 1$ for all $n$ and that $f_n(x) = ne^{-nx} \dfrac{x^2+1}{x^2 + x + 1}$ is integrable, since $0 \le f_n(x) \le ne^{-nx}$ for all $n$. The difference between these integrals satisfies
$$\left| \int_0^\infty n e^{-nx} \, dx - \int_0^\infty ne^{-nx} \frac{x^2+1}{x^2 + x + 1} \, dx \right| = \int_0^\infty \frac{nxe^{-nx}}{x^2+1} \, dx.$$
The maximum value of $te^{-t}$ for $t > 0$ occurs when $t=1$, so that
$$0 \le \frac{nx e^{-nx}}{x^2 + 1} \le \frac{e^{-1}}{x^2 + 1}$$for all $n$ and all $x > 0$. Since $g(x) = \frac{1}{x^2+1}$ is integrable, the dominated convergence theorem gives you
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^\infty \frac{nx e^{-nx}}{x^2 + 1} \, dx = 0.$$

Comment: thank you Umberto!

Answer (score 1):

*Too long for a commant.*

Starting from Umberto P.'s good answer, we can approximate the last integral.

$$I_n=\int\frac{nx e^{-nx}}{x^2 + 1} \, dx=n \int\frac{x e^{-nx}}{(x+i)(x-i)} \, dx=\frac n 2\int \left(\frac{e^{-nx}}{x+i}+\frac{e^{-nx}}{x-i} \right)\,dx$$
$$I_n=\frac n 2\left(e^{i n} \text{Ei}(-n (x+i))+e^{-i n} \text{Ei}(-n (x-i))\right)$$ Then
$$J_n=\int_0^\infty \frac{nx e^{-nx}}{x^2 + 1} \, dx=n \left(\frac{1}{2} (\pi -2 \text{Si}(n)) \sin (n)-\text{Ci}(n) \cos (n)\right)$$ Using thr series expansions of the sine and cosine integrals for large values of $n$, we ned with
$$J_n=\frac{1}{n}-\frac{6}{n^3}+\frac{120}{n^5}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^7}\right)$$